# Wordpress get posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I'm trying to get the post content and post it on my index.php. Right now, nothing will show up for this code.

```
<?php 
$post = get_posts( array( 'name' => 'title' ) );
echo $post->post_title;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do it within the loop, here is an example from codex:

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried this but no luck: <ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'name' => 'title');
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

Comment: that's because there is no field 'name' - look it up in the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: use $my_posts[0]->post_content to achieve what you need, read more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post#Return

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get the post content by passing the post id

`$content = get_post_field('post_content', $my_postid);`

and to get the post name use the following code

`echo $post->post_name;`

hope this works for you.